solving a system equations with Groebner basis
We have the equations:
$$ x+y+z=3\\x^2+y^2+z^2=5 \\x^3+y^3+z^3=7 $$
Using Groebner bases techniques, i want to find : $$x^5+y^5+z^5 \\and\\ x^6+y^6+z^6$$
\
What I did was to find a Groebner basis, in order to easily solve the system, with the help of Wolfram Alpha, but the solution I'm getting is not helping me to proceed. What should I do? \
i find this:


This can be solved without Groebner bases (search here!). But it also works with Groebner bases. Enter as additional equation, say, $x^5+y^5+z^5=a$. As an example, read this post, or this one.

thank you. But i want with Groebner bases

Put in the known equations in $x,y,z$ and an additional equation $x^5+y^5+z^5=a$ with a new variable $a$. Then a reduced Groebner basis is given by
$$
\{3z^3 - 9z^2 + 6z + 2,
y^2 + yz + z^2 - 3y - 3z + 2,
3a - 29,
x + y + z - 3\}
$$
Hence $x^5+y^5+z^5=\frac{29}{3}$.

thank you so much!

Once you have the Groebner basis for the ideal corresponding to the equations, you can use the PolynomialReduce function to find the reduction of another polynomial modulo the ideal -- and if the system implies a value for the other polynomial, that reduction will often give a constant.  For example:
PolynomialReduce[x^5+y^5+z^5, GroebnerBasis[{x+y+z-3, x^2+y^2+z^2-5, x^3+y^3+z^3-7}, {x,y,z}], {x,y,z}] [[2]]

gives a result of $\frac{29}{3}$.
(Note, however, that in some cases you might not get a constant remainder even if there is a forced value -- for example, it might turn out that for some constant $C$, $p(x,y,z) - C$ is not in the ideal, but $(p(x,y,z) - C)^2$ is in the ideal.  In those cases, you may need to use a procedure more like the one in the answer by Dietrich Burde; in such cases, you will not get a linear polynomial in terms of the additional variable $a$ in the reduced Groebner basis, but you should get some multiple of a power of a linear polynomial.)
